# how to empty image on click of cross button of modal in cropper plugin.?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am using this plugin https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper.
I want to clear the image on click of cross button in bootstrap modal. I am using cropper plugin of jquery. I also tried the reset and clear functions of cropper but it does not work for me. Plzz give me answer.

Comment: You want to remove X cross button image on click of it?

Comment: No. i want when i click on X this button ,then it empty image in bootstrap modal

Comment: Provide the code that you have tried yet ?

Comment: $("#resetImage").click(function() {$image.cropper("reset"); });

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle of this code?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/fA5yXXBdv3NUqZhy7Fgz?p=preview..

Comment: You want to remove the selected image preview when clicked on X button? right ?

Comment: yess...u r right.

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#clear').click(function(){
        $('#img').attr('src', '');
        // clear the src or remove the img tag and regenerate it.
    });
});
</script>

<body>

<?php
    $str =  base64_encode(file_get_contents("https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS1W0lHe_4U8pF3j7Ij_wxw-qx_N8ww713xOLWwBolGcUbBFvt5"));

    echo "<img id='img' src='data:image/jpeg;base64, $str' width='100' height='100' >";
?>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="clear">Clear</a>
</body>
</html>
```